# Output line number to generated document in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there any tag that allows to output the line number of the file. I mean if if have `file jsp`

```
<html>
<something>
</html>
```

will output

```
<html>
2
</html>
```

Does this `<something>` exist? :)

A more precise use case is the following:

```
<script>
  var x=1;
  //${some_jsp_var} line-number-here
  <c:if test="${whatever}">
    func1();
    //line-number-here
  </c:if>
</script>
```

In fact the jsp code is used to generate a js file.

Comment: What would that number tell you? If it should be printed on the page, you might get multiple numbers in one line since the linebreaks in the JSP are ignored by the browser (they might not even be added to the generated html).

Comment: It's for debugging. To add some good old "printf" and see what code is executed.

Comment: Just don't put Java code in JSP files.

Comment: I agree with BalusC, use tags and expressions instead. However, if you really need that output, why don't you just write it in your Java code? And if you set a breakpoint on the JSP a decent debugger should be able to tell you which line it works on.

Comment: Sorry guys but it really seems you do not understand the problem. As said is for debugging purpose. Any ugly code will do. Moreover it's out of question to rewrite all in Java.

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering. I will to resign myself about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, as when that JSP is executing, it's not the JSP code per-se that's being ran, but the .class corresponding file to which it has been translated by the servlet engine.

Comment: I know, this does things a little harder to implement, but not impossible. I could think to some custom tag that maybe can do that. But in my case adding a tag for this debug finctionality is not an option.

Comment: However, you CAN debug certain pars of your JSP code (like the JSTL tags parts, and scriptlet parts), i.e. with eclipse you just add a break point inside the JSP, then start your web-app server in debug, mode, conenct to it and access the JSP. Your break point will stop execution so you can atleast know which parts of a logic block are executed, etc. However since the actual debugging is happening on a Java class (obtained from the JSP code) you will not be able to see variables and values for the variables declared in your JSP tags, etc

Comment: I know. Debug is not an available option too unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your use case is here, but you may be able to accomplish something close to what you want using Javascript. In particular, I think you could do something close to what you describe with one line of jQuery (but I'm not a jQuery guru by any stretch, so I may be off base there).

But I'm thinking you probably just don't want to spit out line numbers, and are using that as a test for something else. If you can describe your use case in a bit more detail we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well not sure. In fact the jsp file is a js file too. So js can output line numbers, but I would like to have numbers in the js file itself